# C++ application run only when use local windows debugger, not which exe file

Tags: c++, debugging, runtime, abort

When I use Local Windows Debugger in Visual Studio 2017 my application runs and works, but when I try run my .exe file I get an error like:

> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
>   Debug Error!
>   `abort()` has been called
>   (Press Retry to debug the application".

When I click Retry button my computer hangs.

I tried changing the SDK version and Platform Toolset but that was unsuccessful.

I use `c++` language in Console. This is quite big project which I got from another developer.
How can I repair it?

Comment: I forget writting that I tryied also clean the solution and recompile it but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Do note that on SE sites you can always [edit] your posts to improve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to clean the solution and recompile it.

If you compile it with debug mode you can attach the visual studio debugger to the external running application. 
[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-an-executable-not-part-of-a-visual-studio-solution?view=vs-2019)